# Can prajapatis marry their own biological grand daughters or great grand daughters?

Tags: matsya-purana

[image]

Chapter 23 of the Matsya Purana mentions that after the completion of Soma's Rajasuya, 9 devis (Lakshmi, Sinivali, Dyuti, Trishti, Prabha, Kuhu, Keerti, Vasu) got smitten with Soma and abandoned their husbands(Vishnu, Kardama etc.,). These verses show their names and call Sinivali as the wife of Kardama Prajapati.

There are two Sinivalis as far as I know. Kardama's daughter Shraddha, who married to Angiras and begot Brihaspati, Sinivali and others. Brihaspati too had a daughter named Sinivali.

Or there is any third Sinivali or second Kardama?

Comment: What is your actual question? The one in the title or the last line of the body? (Someone flagged this for closure with the reason: "Needs details or clarity This question should include more details and clarify the problem.")

Comment: @sv The title of the question itself is my real question. The question arised in my mind due to the above verse (ie in case of kardama and sinivali.). If someone answered my question they cannot answer unless they answered last line of my question. Either answering any one of the two automatically answers other. The 1st paragraph provides the context of these verse. The second paragraph establishes how kardama is related to both sinivali (ie grand daughter/great grand daughter).

Comment: If the answer to my question is yes, the one answering should prove this by showing some other examples in shastra. If a no, they cannot answer without adressing the last line of my question.Because the answer to be a No, they should prove that either kardama and sinivali are not related biologically/ or there exists some other kardama or sinivali.